# Creating a nested model by hand in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a `recipe` form that also `has_many` ingredients. Through some (beside the point) out of pattern choices, I end up with parameters that look like this being passed to my 'create' action on the 'Recipes' controller:

```
{
   "commit"   =>"Create Recipe",
   "authenticity_token"   =>"qIeydCyOetcmu2bba3BM9X7HSXXtiFt7cuyuK7yvTPc=",
   "utf8"   =>"✓",
   "recipe"   =>   {
      "title"      =>"",
      "url"      =>"",
      "site"      =>"",
      "instructions"      =>"",
      "ingredients_attributes"      =>      {
         "0"         =>         {
            "quantity"            =>"5",
            "name" => "flour"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to hammer this into a model to save all at once, but with out the benefit of a form builder. I've tried various ways to get this saved into my model when I call `@recipe.save`, but it always seems to be ignored. I try making it into the array that the model would expect, and that doesn't work either. Here is the controller code I've been messing around with:

```
  def create
    arrayIngredients = [];
    params[:recipe][:ingredients_attributes].values.each do |value|
      arrayIngredients.push value
    end 

    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
    @recipe.ingredients.build = arrayIngredients 
         # at this point this is [{"name"=>"flour"}] and so forth
    @recipe.user_id = current_user.id
    @recipe.title = @recipe.inspect  # just debugging purposes
    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save... # do stuff
```

I feel like I'm very close on this, but am missing one key thing to make this get saved properly (currently on the terminal window it's showing NULL in all the INSERT statements)

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients` to your Recipe model and (if needed) add `attr_accessible :ingredients_attributes`

Comment: Hmm, I already have those set in the model... anything else that could be wrong? Is .build necessary?